# Is it possible to parameterize layout path in pug and expressjs?

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to pass a layout path into a pug file like this. In express:

```
res.send(pug.renderFile(loginPagePath, { layout: layoutPath }));
```

In pug file

```
extends #{layout}
h1 This is a login page
```

It doesn't work. Is it possible, what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to set the `extends` directive's path based on a variable.

It's also unclear why you would want to do that. Surely your login page always uses the same layout template?

If you want to use the same chunk of content (like a login form) on two pages with different templates, the best way to do that is with the `include` directive:

**includes/login-markup.pug**

```
h1 This is a login page
```

**views/login-page-a.pug**

```
extends ../layouts/template-a
include ../includes/login-markup
```

**views/login-page-b.pug**

```
extends ../layouts/template-b
include ../includes/login-markup
```